# Google sheets: Why is my query going onto the wrong row?

Tags: google-sheets

I am so frustrated. I don't know what happened but it was working before. This is my formula:

```
=QUERY(C3:M102,
 "Select sum(C),sum(D),E,sum(F),sum(G),sum(H),sum(I),sum(J),sum(K),sum(L),sum(M)
 where D>0
 group by E
 label sum(C)'',sum(D)'',sum(F)'',sum(G)'',sum(H)'',sum(I)'',sum(J)'',sum(K)'',sum(L)'',sum(M)''")
```

The info I am grabbing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjgA8.jpg

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=QUERY(C3:M102,
 "select sum(C),sum(D),E,sum(F),sum(G),sum(H),sum(I),sum(J),sum(K),sum(L),sum(M)
  where D>0
  group by E
  label sum(C)'',sum(D)'',sum(F)'',sum(G)'',sum(H)'',sum(I)'',sum(J)'',sum(K)'',sum(L)'',sum(M)''", )
```

but this is better:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(C3:M102,
 "select sum(C),sum(D),E,sum(F),sum(G),sum(H),sum(I),sum(J),sum(K),sum(L),sum(M)
  where D>0
  group by E"), "offset 1", )
```

Comment: Good use of `Offset` to eliminate labels.